# Approaching a Divisibility Question

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, diophantine-equations

Perhaps I'm a bit rusty on my number theory, but I have been struggling to figure out how to determine what positive integers $x$ and $y$ satisfy
$$ x-y \text{  divides  } x^2 + y^2 $$

Any thoughts? I have tried looking at a remainder after polynomial division, adding/subtracting multiples of the divisor, and factoring out a gcd term to see if that helped.

Any input would be appreciated.

Edit: If it is any help in answering the question, this is in order to help figure out how to prove the following:
[image]

Comment: Since $x^2 + y^2 = (x^2 - y^2) + 2y^2$, we know that $(x + y) \mid 2y^2$. Perhaps this leads you somewhere? Is that what you meant by *looking at a remainder after polynomial division*?

Comment: How much number theory do you know? What facts about sum of squares do you know? EG Do you know how many solutions there are to $a^2 +b^2 = 2 \times 3^2 \times 5^2 $?

Comment: @CalvinLin I apologize, the question had a typo and instead of (x+y), it should read (x-y). I'll edit the question to correct this typo

Comment: @ManuelGuillen Using a transformation of $(x, y) \rightarrow (x, -y)$, the same process works. You can work through it and let me know if you get stuck anywhere. $\quad$ Do you still want $x + y > 4$, or $ x-y > 4$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve $x^2 + y^2 = k(x-y)$, you basically write it as $(2x-k)^2 + (2y+k)^2 = 2k^2$, and then use facts about the solutions to $a^2+b^2 = N$ alongside parity arguments to count the number of solutions.

---

Observations towards a solution:

1. The condition $x+y > 4$ is somewhat forced / complicates things. For now, we remove that condition and add in the 4 solutions $(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (3, 1) $.
2. For now, we also remove the condition that $x, y$ are positive, and account for that later.
3. If $ \frac{ x^2 + y^2 } { x-y } = \frac{ 1995}{k}$, then $\frac{ (kx)^2 + (ky)^2 } { kx-ky} = 1995$.

   - So, it suffices to find all solutions to $\frac{x^2+y^2}{x-y} = 1995$, then account for the number of factors of $\gcd(x, y)$ that divide 1995.
4. To solve $x^2 + y^2 = 1995 (x-y)$, it is the same as solving $(2x-1995)^2 + (2y+1995)^2 = 2\times 1995^2 $.
5. Now we do number theory, especially using facts about sums of squares

   - Recall that if $ p = 4k+3$ is prime, and $ p ^2 \mid a^2 + b^2$, then $ p \mid a, p \mid b$.
   - Show that $ 399 \mid 2x-1995, 399 \mid 2y + 1995 $.
   - Conclude that the solutions over the integers are $(\frac{2x - 1995}{399}, \frac{2y + 1995}{399}) = ( \pm 1, \pm 7), (\pm 5, \pm 5), (\pm 7, \pm 1)  $
6. Now, we add back the condition that $x, y> 0$.

   - Show that $x$ is positive iff $ \frac{ 2x-1995}{399} > -5$ and $y$ is positive iff $ \frac{2y+1995} {399} > 5$.
   - Hence, $(\frac{2x - 1995}{399}, \frac{2y + 1995}{399}) = ( \pm 1, 7) $
   - Hence $(x, y) = (798, 399), (1197, 399) $.
7. For each of the two solutions, $\gcd(x,y) = 399$ and the number of (positive) divisors of 399 is $\sigma_0(399) = 8$. As mentioned earlier, each divisor is a choice of $k$ that gives a unique solution. For the 8 additional *negative* choices of $k$, we get negative values for $x$ and $y$, which we turn into a valid solution by making both values positive and interchanging them ($(-x,-y)$ becomes $(y,x)$). These solutions are not counted for by the positive $k$ solutions since they give different values for the divisor of 1995 $\frac{x^2+y^2}{x-y}$.
8. Therefore, the final number of solutions is $16 + 16 - 4 = $ **28**

Comment: Thanks for the solution @CalvinLin. Added minor edits to the solution just to correct for the minus sign typo on my end on the problem.

Comment: @ManuelGuillen Thanks. Heads up that at the end, each of those only yield 8 solutions, so there are $8+8 - 4 = 12$ solutions only.

Comment: but don't we consider the negative divisors too for k. We make a negative divisor of 1995 on the right hand side, and then on the left hand side keeping kx and ky positive and switching them so the denominator is negative. So 8 positive divisors and 8 negative divisors for each, 16 + 16 - 4 = 28

Comment: The negative divisors of $k$ results in $x, y$ being negative, so I'm not sure what you're referring to. Can you elaborate, with a specific numerical example? And ensure that it doesn't arise from a $2:1$ or $3:1$ ratio, which are those that we've already accounted for.

Comment: If we take one of the two solutions, say (798, 399) which gives 1995, and take k = 399, we get (2,1) which gives 5. If we take k = -399, we get (-2, -1) which gives -5, but since we want a solution in the positive integers, we simply make the two numbers positive and interchange them: (1,2) gives -5. This is a bijective mapping, and does not create solutions already counted for since this is only for negative k. Therefore, the two solutions each give 16 solutions rather than 8, showing that the number of solutions is 28 as the problem describes

Comment: Ah ic now. Great! Thanks!